# ASP C# query deleting inner joined table

Tags: sql

i have this code for updating, but how about changing it to DELETE not to update. is this posible?

```
update r set r.Status = 'Checked-in' from Reservation r 
inner join GuestInfo g on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
where g.GuestFName = 'firstname' 
and g.GuestLName = 'lastname' 
and r.RoomNo = '103'
```

Comment: I would highly recommend reading up on how to do Delete statements using a Where Clause along with a Select or Sub Query. you are not showing any real effort here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
delete r from Reservation r 
inner join GuestInfo g on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
where g.GuestFName = 'firstname' 
and g.GuestLName = 'lastname' 
and r.RoomNo = '103'
```

Comment: @GrantThomas I see what you mean. I am not sure if deleting the guest info is a good idea... I'll leave as is for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete from Reservation
where id in 
(select r.id from Reservation r 
inner join GuestInfo g on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
where g.GuestFName = 'firstname' 
and g.GuestLName = 'lastname' 
and r.RoomNo = '103')
```

Comment: What is the PK column of your table called?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You can simply just get rid of the `UPDATE` sections and change the keyword to `DELETE`:

```
delete Reservation
from Reservation r 
    inner join GuestInfo g on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
where g.GuestFName = 'firstname' 
and g.GuestLName = 'lastname' 
and r.RoomNo = '103'
```

and in fact, this is very common. There are many times when you need to do a more complex `DELETE` based on conditions, and *many times* `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements can **very easily** be turned into a `DELETE`. As a matter of fact, a place I worked one time, their rule was this:

> Write the `SELECT` statement, and then if it's getting you the data, get rid of `SELECT` and change it to `DELETE` - **but only then.**